# How to split ID received from the backend into 3 parts in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, split, material-ui

**I fetched the backend data like this.**

[image]

but I need to separate this ID into three parts like this.

[image]

How can I do it with react? This is my function code.

```
function getSessinIDChipProps(params: GridRenderCellParams): ChipProps {
  return {
    label: params.value,
    style: {
      background: "#FFEDED",
      color: "black",
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: step 1 - if it's coming to you as a number, convert to string ... step 2 you can use string substring or a regex match to get what you want - something like ``const [, p1, p2, p3] = x.toString().match(/^(\d{3})(\d\d)(\d\d)$/)``

Answer (score 2):

```
let number = 1234567;
let numberString = (number + "")
let numberArr = [numberString.slice(0, 3), numberString.slice(3, 5), numberString.slice(5, 7)]
```

Now, just loop numberArr to display them separately.